# How to make Chrome show beginning and end of long URLs in the URL bar

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-developer-tools

I've been trying to find a Chrome extension that would show the beginning (`www.domain.com/...`) and ending (`someFileorPage.html`) part of a URL, in the omni-bar, truncating the middle part if the URL's too long to fit.

The beginning and ending parts usually provide the most pertinent information, and I thought it'd be useful to be able to see them without clicking and scrolling through the text. How can I get Chrome to display long URLs like this?

[image: Truncated URL]
[image: URL's ending part]

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not "asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation", as the link says.

I'm just asking for a way to do a particular thing, with a popular browser. The link does say that questions about "computer software", are OK.

Comment: I remember seeing this sometime back but I don't see this feature in Chrome ver 38 on Windows. What version are you using? Also, check this Chrome flag fix - http://superuser.com/questions/739846/how-can-i-re-enable-the-path-in-chromes-address-bar

Comment: I'm on Chrome v38.0.2125.104 on OSX 10.10. I did check the Chrome flag fix, but that just enables/disables the whole URL's visibility. Hoping the Chrome devs think about this bit of functionality sometime soon.

Comment: @Qasim have you checked out : http://superuser.com/questions/799275/how-to-restore-the-url-in-google-chromes-omnibox-i-e-always-show-it-without-r

Comment: @TechLife The behavior I'm wanting is a little different. I'm adding a screenshot to illustrate. Chrome just truncates the URL in the middle, IMO the end part is often relevant and significant(someFileorPage.html)

Comment: Increase your screen resolution / decrease text size.  Lol I'm sorry it's not a very professional fix, but I have never heard of that option in Chrome before.  I'll report back if I find something, you might just have to settle for a text size reduction though.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `chrome://flags/#origin-chip-in-omnibox` and set it to `Disabled`.

Comment: I don't have that flag. I'm on OSX/Chrome 43.0.2357.134

Comment: I don't have that flag either :(
Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I don't have that flag either . ( Running Chromium 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) )